# Tabs not working properly when switching in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, camera

I am newbie in native android development. I am using `android studio` for developing an app. I am using `tabbed-activity` and using 3 tabs. All the 3 tabs have separate `classes` and `layouts` with following names as shown in below image.

[image]

The classes and layouts name are same as shown in the image.

My tabs have following features.

1. On first tab i have implemented a `google map v2` which is showing my current gps location with coordinates and a marker on it.
2. On second tab i have implemented a `camera` in which i have placed a button and a `image view`. By pressing the button the camera will show and when i took picture it is showing me on image view. Also this image is saving into my `SD CARD`.
3. In third and final tab i have added a `gird view` which will take those images from the `SD CARD` and show it on the grid.

For `third tab` i followed this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/), so i made 2 `helper` and 1 `adapter` classes separately. The 2 helper classes are `AppConstant` and `Utils` the adapter is named as `GridViewImageAdapter` which extends `BaseAdapter`.

All the above 3 (2 helper and 1 adapter) classes are imported in my `pictures` class.

Now when i run the app for the first time, i am able to see my current location. But when i tap the `camera` tab it goes to the `Util` class and when it doesn't find any file the app crashes. This should not happen because my Util class is only imported in the `pictures` fragment and it's nothing to do with the `camera` fragment. Below is the code section

**Camera.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera, container, false);

    button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.getpicture);
    imageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check permission for CAMERA
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Check Permissions Now
                // Callback onRequestPermissionsResult interceptado na Activity MainActivity
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{CAMERA},
                        Camera.REQUEST_CAMERA);

            }
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );

            }


        }
    });



    return rootView;
}
//For saving image(s)
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
    Log.v(getTag(), root);
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir,fname);
    if (file.exists())file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image is saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Below is my Pictures code

**Pictures.java**

```
import com.example.accurat.faisal.adapter.GridViewImageAdapter;
import com.example.accurat.faisal.helper.Utils;
import com.example.accurat.faisal.helper.AppConstant;
//other imports
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictures, container, false);

    gridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    utils = new Utils(getContext());

    // Initilizing Grid View
    InitilizeGridLayout();

    // loading all image paths from SD card
    imagePaths = utils.getFilePaths();

    // Gridview adapter

    adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(getActivity(), imagePaths, columnWidth);
    /*adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(Pictures.this, imagePaths,
            columnWidth);*/

    // setting grid view adapter
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


    return rootView;
}

private void InitilizeGridLayout() {

    Resources r = getResources();
    float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());

    columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() - ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

    gridView.setNumColumns(AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
    gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
    gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
    gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,
            (int) padding);
    gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
    gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);
}
```

This above class will access `helper` and `adapter` methods. See below for helper methods

**Utils.java**

```
public class Utils {

         // Reading file paths from SDCard
public ArrayList<String> getFilePaths() {
    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    File directory = new File(
            android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);

    // check for directory
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        // getting list of file paths
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

        // Check for count
        if (listFiles.length > 0) {

            // loop through all files
            for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

                // get file path
                String filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();

                // check for supported file extension
                if (IsSupportedFile(filePath)) {
                    // Add image path to array list
                    filePaths.add(filePath);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // image directory is empty
            Toast.makeText(
                    _context,
                    AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                            + " is empty. Please load some images in it !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
        alert.setTitle("Error!");
        alert.setMessage(AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                + " directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        alert.show();
    }

    return filePaths;
   }
}
```

There are other methods as well in this class but i have only posted the above method because when i go to my `pictures` tab this method is called first and it's working for pictures tab but when i go to my `camera` tab again the above method is called and it should be called because there is nothing in my camera class that will access the helper class. I don't know why it's happening as all classes are separate so it should not work like this and i am getting `null exception`

For manifest see below

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.accurat.faisal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Below is the error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.accurat.faisal, PID: 25624
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                  at com.example.accurat.faisal.helper.Utils.getFilePaths(Utils.java:42)
                  at com.example.accurat.faisal.Pictures.onCreateView(Pictures.java:45)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:668)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611)
                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2178)
                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1155)
                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1148)
                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1118)
                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1413)
                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1523)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

`Utlis.java:42` is

```
 // check for directory
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        // getting list of file paths
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

        // Check for count
        if (listFiles.length > 0) {// do the needful
```

While `Pictures.java:42` is `// loading all image paths from SD card
        imagePaths = utils.getFilePaths();`

**Update 1**

After the suggestions of `Mike M` and `Ruben2112` i imported `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to each of my helper and adapter class and also placed a check for `listFiles` in `Utils` class as below

```
 File directory = new File(
            android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);

    // check for directory
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        // getting list of file paths
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

        if (listFiles != null) {// Check for list files
            // Check for count
            if (listFiles.length > 0) {

                // loop through all files
                for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

                    // get file path
                    String filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();

                    // check for supported file extension
                    if (IsSupportedFile(filePath)) {
                        // Add image path to array list
                        filePaths.add(filePath);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // image directory is empty
                Toast.makeText(
                        _context,
                        AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                                + " is empty. Please load some images in it !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
            alert.setTitle("Error!");
            alert.setMessage(AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                    + " directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

Now my app is not crashing but still it's showing me the error on alert box as shown in below image

[image]

After taping ok the app still runs

I am stuck to it and don't know what to do. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: By default, `ViewPager` will load the next adjacent pages, so that they're ready to be pulled on-screen. When you navigate to the second tab, it's readying the third page. Looking at your `Utils` class, it looks like it's going to crash anyway, if `AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM` is indeed a constant. It's crashing because `directory.listFiles()` is returning null. If you're running on Marshmallow or above, are you sure you've handled the permissions correctly? `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is a dangerous permission. You need to request it, just like you are `CAMERA`.

Comment: @MikeM. yes i have added permission checks. And on marshmallow the app crashes but on API < 20 the app won't crash, but still it goes to the `utils` class and display an alert box. I want to know how to handle the switching of tabs

Comment: OK, I don't see the request for the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, so I thought I'd point it out. Anyway, that's what you need to fix, not the tab switching. I'm pretty sure that's going to crash, no matter what. I really don't think it's just because the third page is loaded while you're on the second. It's because you can't read the `PHOTO_ALBUM` directory.

Comment: I do have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in my `Camera`. Also if i create a folder and paste it on my device, then the app works perfectly.

Comment: OK, I think I'm following you. Is `AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM` the `"/saved_images"` folder? If so, then it's because the third page is trying to access that folder before the second page creates it. You'll have to decide how you want to handle that. You could ask for all permissions up front, and create that folder as soon as possible. Or you could put off loading the `GridView`; i.e., don't try to load it in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: @MikeM. yes you are right, it does finding the folder first while it's not created it gives error. Also as per your and ` Ruben2112` suggestions i have done something with the code. Please see the `Update 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134678/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 0):

> This should not happen because my Util class is only imported in the pictures fragment and it's nothing to do with the camera fragment.

An important thing to realise when using tabs is that the tabs directly next to the tab that is opened, also gets loaded in. This is so the tab already is loaded so the transition is smoother and that's how it is possible to swipe to go to the next tab.

Comment: So what's the solution for it?

Comment: You probably need to check if listFiles is null after getting the directory.listFiles();

Comment: Ok i'll do a check for it

Comment: As per your suggestion, i have done some thing with my code. Please see the `update 1`